# Create repeat excel macro code until no more text mentions

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this macro code using the record function.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Find(What:="Text to find", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("E5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "text to enter"
    Range("D6").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Text to find", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "text to enter"       
End Sub
```

I need this macro to continue through the same column until it cannot find any more instances of the searched for word without it going back to the top of the column.

So it starts in a column, every time it finds a specified word it tabs across 1 column and pastes in a specified word.

It continues to search for the specified word in the same column until it cannot find it without starting at the top of the column.

Hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand but I think what your looking for is:

```
For each cell in columns(4).cells
    If cell.value="Text to find" Then Cell.offset(0,1) = "Text to enter"
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find` and `FindNext` to do this quickly, ie to:

- search column D for the text in `StrOld`
- enter any matches into column E with the text in `StrIn`

**code**

```
Sub Recut()
Dim strAddress As String
Dim StrIn As String
Dim StrOut As String
Dim rng1 As Range
StrOld = "Old"
StrIn = "New"

Set rng1 = Range("D:D").Find(StrOld, , xlFormulas, xlWhole, , , True)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        strAddress = rng1.Address
        Do
            rng1.Offset(0, 1) = StrIn
            Set rng1 = Range("D:D").FindNext(rng1)
        Loop While Not rng1 Is Nothing And rng1.Address <> strAddress
End If
End Sub
```